# Calculator returns 0 value, can‘t input double numbers

Tags: c++, calculator, bison, dev-c++, bisonc++

I formatted the `temp` as `double`, but it returns `0` when inputting numbers without decimal point, and inputting numbers with decimal point results in "invalid expression".

```
%{
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int valid=0
double temp;
%}
%token num
%left '+''-'
%left '*''/'
%left '^'
%nonassoc UMINUS
%%
expr1: expr { temp=$1; }
expr : expr '+' expr { $$=$1+$3; }
| expr '-' expr { $$=$1-$3; }
| expr '*' expr { $$=$1*$3; }
| expr '/' expr { if($3==0) { valid=1; $$=0; } else { $$=$1/$3; } }
| '(' expr ')' { $$=$2; }
| '-' expr { $$=-1*$2; }
| num { $$=yylval;}
;
%%
#include<stdlib.h>
int yyerror(){
printf("\nInvalid expression!\n");
valid=2;
return 0;
}
int yyparse();
double main(double argc, char *argv[]){
extern FILE *yyin;
++argv;
--argc;
yyin=fopen(argv[0],"r");
yyparse();
if(valid==1){
printf("\nDivision by 0!\n");
}
if(valid==0){
printf("\nValid expression!\n");
printf("The value evaluated is %d\n",temp);
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What am I looking at here...

Comment: Better recheck the code you posted. Looks like it got chewed up up some in transit.

Comment: If you are using a parser generator you should say what kind, don't make people guess please. And tag it with the name of the parser generator.

Comment: Code generator. That would make more sense than my first guess: C'thulu.

Comment: So I am assuming that is yacc or bison.  yylval is not defined in this code so I am assuming you have a lex or flex file somewhere.  It probably defines yylval to be int.  Plus the parsing for the token num is missing and that is probably where the error is.  Can you post the scanner code?

Comment: it uses bison, sorry i forgot

Answer (score 1):

Since you define neither `YYSTYPE` nor `%union`, you get the default `YYSTYPE`, which is `int`.  So all of your floating point values will be converted to integers when you use them as semantic values.

Add a `#define YYSTYPE double` to the first part of your grammar (in between the `%{`...`%}`), and it will be a double instead.